# Is it possible to use a method(returning an Observable) inside side effect operator(doOnNext())?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I just started to introduce RxJava to my existing project.

I have a method *(in Data Layer)* for DB operation named `getUser()` which returns an `Observable<User>`.
I make use of this method in 3 different places. Out of the 3, in 2 places I need the method to return an `Observable<User>`. But, the problem strikes me at the one place where I need to access this method inside a `doOnNext()`*side effect operator*.

AFAIK, `doOnNext()` doesn't alter the stream and continues on the previous thread. And if the stream is already on the io thread, we can continue a new background operations without having to create/use an Observable.

**Snippet**

```
getDataManager().getUser(id)
                        .doOnNext(user -> getDataManager().insertUser(user))
                        .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                        .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                        .subscribe()
```

This `insertUser()` method returns `Observable<Long>`, which is how I want it for the other parts. But for this *side effect operator* I need it to return only Long.

Is there any way I can remove the `Observable` wrapper? Or do I need to create two different methods?

Comment: How are you going to use the `Long` that is being returned by `insertUser(user)`?

Comment: I don't think the return type has any relevance to the above question. Do you think there is any connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dependent computations/IO that return `Observable`, use the `flatMap` or `concatMap` operators in general.

```
getDataManager()
.getUser(id)
.concatMap(user ->
    getDataManager()
    .insertUser(user)
)
.subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
.observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
.subscribe()
```

If you still need the original `user`, simply map it back:

```
getDataManager()
.getUser(id)
.concatMap(user ->
    getDataManager()
    .insertUser(user)
    .ignoreElements()
    .andThen(Observable.just(user))
)
.subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
.observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
.subscribe()
```

Comment: Yes, very much right. But I guess I forgot to mention another point in the question. Using `concatMap()` will alter the stream. I expect the stream to be unaltered, that's why I am playing around with `doOnNext()`. I make use of the `User` object from the source stream inside of subscribe's `onNext()`.

Comment: That's kind of an important detail you forgot. I've updated the answer for that case.